# Firefox on Android fixed positioned element gets cut off when animating translate

Tags: android, firefox, css-position, css-animations

The scenario is simple. There's a `position:fixed` element which is higher than the viewport. If I animate `transform:translateY` (using CSS animations or JavaScript) it moves but the parts that were outside of the viewport earlier stay invisible and never appear.

The bin contains the same element with `position:absolute` as comparison. It's working as expected in other browsers.

http://jsbin.com/yonisekawe/5

Any idea on how to workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a feasible workaround that I post as an answer but I'd still like this to get fixed in Firefox.

The workaround is simple: wrap the translated element inside another `position:fixed` div and position itself `absolute`.

Before

```
<body>
    <div style="position:fixed;">Look ma, I'm getting translated!</div>
</body>
```

After

```
<body>
    <div style="position:fixed;">
        <div style="position:absolute;">Look ma, I'm getting translated!</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This will cause the element to get correctly updated while translating without getting cut off.

Comment: I'm so glad you found this work around. Want to add this works with absolute positioned elements too (wrapping it in another absolute position element)